# SAS, forcing the creation of columns when using proc transpose

Tags: sql, sas

I'm fairly new to SAS and need some help, if this is at all possible.

My data looks something like this

[sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aB1in.png)

For now, I only have 201801, but I want the follow code to work for all months in 2018, or rather force every yearmonth to show up

```
PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = have OUT = want PREFIX = primary_;
    BY member_no;
    ID yearmonth_pd;
    VAR desc;
    OPTIONS MISSING = ' ';
RUN;
```

This purpose of this, is that later on I want to left join every yearmonth_pd to other information, but this returns the error

```
ERROR: Column primary_201802 could not be found in the table/view identified with the
   correlation name B.
```

We are entering the the variables manually as such b.primary_201801, b.primary_201802,....

but were hoping this could be done without the need for that, as other departments use the code, but don't necessarily know how to code.

Basically, I want something like the following (the table on top is what I'm looking for and the one below is what data generally looks like)

[desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rl9QR.png)

Thanks all!

Comment: How do you know what columns are missing?  Is that information that is available, or implied, by the input data?  Or something that you know externally?  Your transpose code will create a column for every distinct value or `yearmonth_pd` in the input dataset.  What is your source of other values of that variable?

Comment: Don't post photographs of your data.  Especially when it is just a handful of values.  Just paste it in as a code block.

Answer (score 1):

You did not indicate if `yearmonth_pd` is a string, a formatted date value, or simply an integer that is an encoded representation `yyyymm` for year and month.  I'll presume simple integer.

You will need to prepend a by group of extra rows to `have` such that there is one row per target column.

```
data all_months;
  member_no = 0;
  do yearmo_pd = 201801 to 201812;
    output;
  end;
run;

data haveFull;
  set all_months have;
run;

PROC TRANSPOSE DATA = have OUT = want(where=(member_no ne 0)) PREFIX = primary_;
    BY member_no;
    ID yearmonth_pd;
    VAR desc;
    OPTIONS MISSING = ' ';
RUN;
```

This approach can also be used to force a certain column order in the `out=` table when the `data=` has sparse or out of sequence `id` values.

Comment: This worked, thank you! Thanks also to everybody for tips on formatting my questions. This is my first on the site, so I appreciate the guidance!